# How to override wordpress plugin template file that is not in "templates" folder?

Tags: wordpress

If a plugin's template file located in 'templates' folder, we can easily override in child theme by adding a folder named after the plugin, and copy the same file into it. However Some plugin names template folder as 'public' or 'views', how to override ?

I had created the folder named after the plugin, and then subfolders following the plugin structure but unsuccessful .

the plugin template structure /wp-content/plugins/woo-product-slider/public/views/shortcoderender.php .
I created /mytheme-child/woo-product-slider/public/views/shortcoderender.php , /mytheme-child/woo-product-slider/views/shortcoderender.php , /mytheme-child/woo-product-slider/public/shortcoderender.php , /mytheme-child/woo-product-slider/templates/shortcoderender.php all failed, nothing happen.

Any help please ?

Comment: Did you try just `/mytheme-child/woo-product-slider/shortcoderender.php`?

Comment: oh, i haven't thought of this ... i will try

Comment: just tried /mytheme-child/woo-product-slider/shortcoderender.php , nothing happen at all ..

Comment: You could check if the calling function or the shortcode is pluggable - Then you could just call your own template.

Comment: where or how to check if the calling function or the shortcode is pluggable .. there is a public function within the file public function that look like this wps_shortcode( $attributes ) {
  extract( shortcode_atts( array(
   'id' => '',
  ), $attributes, 'woo_product_slider' ) );

  $post_id = $attributes['id']; .... etc.. quite long

Answer (score 0):

I've just looked at the source for [Product Slider for WooCommerce](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/woo-product-slider/) and it doesn't look like those file loads are being filtered or that theme versions are checked for - it's hard-coded to load them only from the plugin.

Not all plugins allow you to add your own template files unfortunately. In this case, since it looks like what you're trying to modify is a shortcode, I would recommend making a copy of the `wps_shortcode()` function in `shortcoderender.php` and adding a copy of it to your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
function my_wps_shortcode( $attributes ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => '',
    ), $attributes, 'my_woo_product_slider' ) );

    //  ...and then all the rest of the code
}

add_shortcode('my_woo_product_slider', 'my_wps_shortcode');
```

The shortcode function is *pretty* extensive, but there are also plenty of filtered values in there, so you may be able to achieve what you want using filters rather than replicating the entire shortcode function.

Comment: I will try on this

Comment: @LimKhengSin If this works for you, don't forget to accept my answer 

Comment: I added the suggested function function my_wps_shortcode( $attributes ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => '',
    ), $attributes, 'my_woo_product_slider' ) );

    //  ...and then all the rest of the code
}

add_shortcode('my_woo_product_slider', 'my_wps_shortcode'); to my theme's function.php and apply the new short code my_woo_product_slider to website ... page section containing the code was blank and page alignment also a bit out.

Comment: @LimKhengSin Right, but did you actually replicate the function from the `shortcoderender.php` file, rather than just copy my code? And did you replace the `[woo_product_slider]` shortcode with `[my_woo_product_slider]` in your page?